# Stored Procedure with parameters how to prevent SQL Injection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters, sql-injection

I created a stored procedure that searches tables based off of user input. I think this code is at risk for SQL injection, so I tested with several queries that I expected to drop a table, but to my surprise the table was not dropped. I'm wondering if this query is actually fine or am I missing something?

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(200) = ';DROP TABLE DeleteMe;--'

SELECT f.Name 
FROM [Firm] AS f
WHERE f.Name LIKE '%' + @Query + '%';
```

I tried several queries, all variations on the theme above.

Comment: You're just concatenating strings for a *value* in a fixed query not a query *itself* that gets dynamically executed. So your code is fine in regard to SQL injection.

Comment: This is no less safe than `PRINT @Query` -- there is no way to get what's in `@Query` to execute when it's used as a parameter. If you build this value client-side by concatenating strings, there's a risk; if you build a query text and then feed it to `EXEC` (either directly or through `sp_executesql`) there's a risk; if you don't do any of these things you're OK no matter how you end up using your parameters.

Comment: What happens if `@Query` is the string "O'Reilly"? It will result in a syntax error because of imbalanced single-quote characters. Not all SQL injections are intentional by some malicious attacker. Some are accidental and result in no data loss, but only unforeseen errors.

Answer (score -2):

There are ways to prevent SQL Injection:

1 Using Prepared Statements(with Parameterized Queries)
2- Using Stored Procedures
3- Validating user input
4- Limiting privileges
5- Hiding info from the error message
6- Updating your system
7- Keeping database credentials separated and encrypted
8- Disabling shell and any other functionalities you don't need

you can read more here : https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/08/sql-injection-attack-explained-with-example.html

Comment: If you "injected" that the effective end result would be `WHERE f.Name LIKE '%%'';select * from sys.tables--%'` -- which is perfectly safe. Do not confuse creating query strings through concatenation with building strings at runtime through concatenating parameter values.